# How to specify RPM_BUILD_ROOT for sbt-native-package

Tags: sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play project that I would like to deploy via RPM. I'm trying to use SBT to build the RPM, on CentOS, using the sbt-native-packager RPM plugin. 
At the end I gt the rpm package.
But it stored in directory under %appname%/target/rpm
How can I use my own path for rpm buildroot tree?
Say, for example /home/build/buildroot

**Sbt-native-packager version in use 0.8.0.**

Comment: What's the purpose of doing so? You could change the `target in Rpm` setting, but I highly recommend against that. The build will only work on a machine that has this path.

Comment: Trainig to solve issue with sbt rpm:packageBin task. 
It's prints me out like that:
**[info] Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /tmp/sbt_f3554995/rpm-tmp.SDC7gK
[error] + umask 022
[error] + cd /data/src/auth-server/target/rpm/BUILD
[error] + '[' /data/src/auth-server/target/rpm/buildroot '!=' / ']'
[error] + rm -rf /data/src/auth-server/target/rpm/buildroot**

Answer (score 1):

The simple (rpm config centric) answer is to configure %_topdir in ~/.rpmmacros before invoking rpmbuild. SBT may be adding additional complexities.

Comment: It still does not help me.
Looks like sbt-native-apckager dont care about variables specifyed at user enviroment level. I have following configuration of macros:

 rpm --showrc|grep topdir
 -14: _builddir  %{_topdir}/BUILD
 -14: _buildrootdir      %{_topdir}/BUILDROOT
 -14: _rpmdir    %{_topdir}/RPMS
 -14: _sourcedir %{_topdir}/SOURCES
 -14: _specdir   %{_topdir}/SPECS
 -14: _srcrpmdir %{_topdir}/SRPMS
 -14: _topdir    /home/centos/rpmbuild